# Raster of land area within 15 km radius

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, area

I have two polygon layers, one of Land and one of Reef. I would like to create two rasters, of the Reef layer, who's values are the area of Land within 15 km of each cell, and the area of Reef within 15 km of each cell.

However I am unsure which function, or combination of functions, I need to use to complete this task.

Comment: I since received a reply elsewhere. The tool I was looking for is the Focal statistics tool. Specifically the methods is to:
 
1.       Create a raster of your reefs where the value of the cell is 0 (or NoData) if there is no reef, and a value of the area (e.g. cell value = 1 if cell is 1 ha) if the cell is reef.

Comment: 2.       Use the Focal Statistics tool, set Neighbourhood to ‘Circle’, keep Units as Cell, and set the radius to the number of cells that would equal 15 km (e.g. if using 1 ha cells, 15000 m / 100 m = 150 cells). I recommend using Units as Cell rather than Map, because if you use Map you need to make sure everything is in an equi-distant projection.
3.       Set Statistics type to SUM.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer to your own question, make it easier for other to find it